# Passing an str to SQL alchemy Query

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Actually I have a code which is fetching necessary details from a text file.

Here I am fetching the some id from text file.

Then I need to pass the same in to SQLAlchemy query to fetch the results.

But I am no t getting the results as needed here.

here it is the code:

```
addys = ','.join('"{}"'.format(''.join(tenant)) for tenant in tenants if tenant)
#print "%s" % (addys)

# cleanup and close files
files.close()

query1 = query1.filter(model.name == "in-addr.arpa.")
query2 = query2.filter(model.tenant_id.in_([addys]))
```

Here type of 'addys' is as follows:

```
<type 'str'>
```

I am not getting the result here as needed.

Some one help me with the same.

Note:

While printing the addys getting the results as follows which is obviously correct:

```
"1235b3a73ad24b9c86cf301525310b24","cbdf25542c194a069464f69efff4859a"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Argument for `_in` method should be an array of ids, but you pass to it list with one element - string with all id, divided by commas. You need split string with ids and pass them as list:

```
query = query.filter(model.tenant_id.in_(addys.split(',')))
```

Or change your previous lines:

```
tenant_ids = [''.join(tenant) for tenant in tenants if tenant]
query = query.filter(model.tenant_id.in_(tenant_ids))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
But its not seems to be working.In query it is getting in  as follows:
 ['1235b3a73ad24b9c86cf301525310b24'], ['cbdf25542c194a069464f69efff4859a'])\n"]

Comment: If I am using your first solution it is getting displayed as follows while I was printing a query:

WHERE domains.tenant_id IN (:tenant_id_1, :tenant_id_2)) AS anon_1

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know structure of `tenants`, now second solution have to work too.

Comment: Thanks Dude. Second one is perfect.!:)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to join the strings, it's enough to:

```
addys = [tenant for tenant in tenants if tenant]
```

and

```
query2 = query2.filter(model.tenant_id.in_(addys))
```

Comment: But its not seems to be working.In query it is getting in  as follows:
 ['1235b3a73ad24b9c86cf301525310b24'], ['cbdf25542c194a069464f69efff4859a'])\n"]

Comment: If I am following your solution value here is getting passed as a LIST.
May be that is the issue here. As well as \n was also there, May be that one is an issue